# OpenCV detect rectangle with the largest width

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm trying to get this rectangle from that image:
[image: Wanted rectangle]

Found this solution using OpenCV:

```
 private Bitmap findRectangle(Bitmap src) throws Exception {
        Mat imageMat = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(src, imageMat);

        Mat imgSource=imageMat.clone();

        Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        //find the contours
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Imgproc.findContours(imageMat, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

        Imgproc.Canny(imageMat,imageMat,0,255);
        Bitmap canny=Bitmap.createBitmap(imageMat.cols(),imageMat.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(imageMat,canny);

        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imageMat, imageMat, new  org.opencv.core.Size(1, 1), 2, 2);
        Bitmap blur=Bitmap.createBitmap(imageMat.cols(),imageMat.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(imageMat,blur);

        MatOfPoint temp_contour = contours.get(0); //the largest is at the index 0 for starting point

        for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
            temp_contour = contours.get(idx);
            //check if this contour is a square

            MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f( temp_contour.toArray() );

            int contourSize = (int)temp_contour.total();
            MatOfPoint2f approxCurve_temp = new MatOfPoint2f();
            Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new_mat, approxCurve_temp, contourSize*0.05, true);

            if (approxCurve_temp.total() == 4) {
                MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint( approxCurve_temp.toArray() );
                Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);
                Imgproc.rectangle(imgSource, new Point(rect.x,rect.y), new Point(rect.x+rect.width,rect.y+rect.height), new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 3);

            }

        }
        Bitmap analyzed=Bitmap.createBitmap(imgSource.cols(),imgSource.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(imgSource,analyzed);

        return analyzed;
    }
```

The best i got was this:
[image: result image]

The problem is that the rectangle isn't perfect, maybe find the white numbers inside of that can be a best option, but i don't know too much of OpenCV.

Original image:
[image]

Comment: If you are using mobile camera you can make rectangle place-holder on the screen before taking the picture. That increases your detection accuracy and eliminate noise at first level. Then try to find biggest contour in image. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very simple C++ implementation which tries to search for the text box. The accuracy of the detection depends on three parameters:

The **thresh** value provided to `cv::threshold` function to convert gray image to binary.

The **height/width ratio**, since the height of the text box is relatively smaller than the width, and the **area** of the text box.

```
Mat img = imread("image.jpg",-1), gray, binary;

/*pre-processing steps*/
uchar thresh = 80;
cvtColor(img, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
GaussianBlur(gray, gray, Size(7,7), 0);
// change the thresh value to fine tune this program for your images
threshold(gray, binary, thresh, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);

/*contour searching*/
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> contours;
std::vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(binary, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

/*Filtering contours based on height/width ratio and bounding box area*/
std::vector<Rect> boxes;
double box_ratio = 0.3;
int box_area = 20000;

for(auto& cnt : contours)
{
    auto box = minAreaRect(cnt).boundingRect();
    // we are searching for a rectangle which a has relatively large area,
    // and the height is smaller than the width, so the
    // height/width ratio should be small. Change the these two values for fine tuning
    if((min(box.width,box.height)/double(max(box.width,box.height)) < box_ratio) && box.area() > box_area )
    {
        boxes.push_back(box);
    }

}

Mat txt_box = img(boxes.at(0));
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the almost same solution on java:

```
private Bitmap findRoi(Bitmap sourceBitmap) {

    Mat sourceMat = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CV_8UC3);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(sourceBitmap, sourceMat);

    Mat grayMat = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CV_8UC3);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(sourceMat, grayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.threshold(grayMat, grayMat, 125, 200, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

    // find contours
    List<MatOfPoint> whiteContours = new ArrayList<>();
    Rect largestRect = null;
    Imgproc.findContours(grayMat, whiteContours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // find appropriate bounding rectangles
    for (MatOfPoint contour : whiteContours) {
        RotatedRect boundingRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray()));
        double rectangleArea = boundingRect.size.area();

        // test min ROI area in pixels
        if (rectangleArea > 10000) {
            Point rotated_rect_points[] = new Point[4];
            boundingRect.points(rotated_rect_points);
            Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(new MatOfPoint(rotated_rect_points));

            // test horizontal ROI orientation and aspect ratio
            if (rect.width > 3 * rect.height) {
                if (largestRect == null) {
                    largestRect = rect;
                } else {
                    if (rect.width > largestRect.width) {
                        largestRect = rect;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Mat roiMat = new Mat(sourceMat, largestRect);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(roiMat.cols(), roiMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(roiMat, bitmap);
    return bitmap;
}
```

[image: ROI rectangle]

Also, you can use additional information: red number places on the right.