# how to select the edge of a glossy gray sticker with text inside?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Here is the original image.

My problem is the draw contour select also the details inside the sticker.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

while True:
    img = cv2.imread("orig.jpg")
    img_original = img.copy()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (15, 15), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, thresh1, thresh2, 3)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(edged, (1, 1), iterations=2)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    cv2.drawContours(img_original, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Output", img_original)

    cv2.waitKey(300)
```

I expect to have only the outside of sticker to have the contour. Please help me I've been stuck now for hours. Thank you.

Comment: Your first image link is not working, please check it.

Comment: @stateMachine Hello! I already updated the image link. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV detect rectangle with the largest width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209533/opencv-detect-rectangle-with-the-largest-width)

Comment: There are plenty of answered questions to detect a rectangle contour in an image using OpenCV and most of them would also apply to your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do that in Python/OpenCV.

You were close but had a few issue.  First you need to trim the image to remove the excess black at the sides. Second you over-blurred the image.  Third, you did not say what your Canny edge thresholds were and I suspect you did not make the first one low enough. Third I just extracted the largest contour and drew that one rather than trying to draw all contours.

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('orig_chart.jpg')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# trim the sides by 15 pixels to remove excess black regions
img2 = img[15:h-15, 15:w-15]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur slightly
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)

# get canny edges
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 20, 250)

# pad edged to size of input
edged2 = np.zeros((h,w), dtype=np.uint8)
edged2[15:h-15, 15:w-15] = edged

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(edged2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw largest contour on copy of input
result = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(result, [big_contour], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('orig_chart_edges.jpg', edged)
cv2.imwrite('orig_chart_contour.jpg', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("edged", edged)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Canny Edges:

[image]

Resulting Contour on Input:

[image]